# GET a coupon code via URL and apply it in WooCommerce Checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, coupon

I have a WooCommerce website and when customer add-to-cart a product, it is get redirected to checkout page, so cart page is not accessible.

I would like to apply coupon via URL (`GET`) on checkout page, with something like `https://example.com/?coupon_code=highfive`.

When customer click this URL then the coupon code is stored in browser sessions. Then if he add-to-cart any product then the coupon is applied into checkout page.

Is this possible?

Comment: This question is absolutely **NOT too broad**… and can be done with few lines of code (5 minutes to be answered max).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Update 3:** This can be done in a very simple way with the following 2 hooked functions:

- The first one will catch the coupon code in the Url and will set it in WC_Sessions.
- The second one will apply the coupon code from session in checkout page.

Here is this code:

```
add_action('init', 'get_custom_coupon_code_to_session');
function get_custom_coupon_code_to_session(){
    if( isset($_GET['coupon_code']) ){
        // Ensure that customer session is started
        if( isset(WC()->session) && ! WC()->session->has_session() )
            WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie(true);
            
        // Check and register coupon code in a custom session variable
        $coupon_code = WC()->session->get('coupon_code');
        if(empty($coupon_code)){
            $coupon_code = esc_attr( $_GET['coupon_code'] );
            WC()->session->set( 'coupon_code', $coupon_code ); // Set the coupon code in session
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'add_discout_to_checkout', 10, 0 );
function add_discout_to_checkout( ) {
    // Set coupon code
    $coupon_code = WC()->session->get('coupon_code');
    if ( ! empty( $coupon_code ) && ! WC()->cart->has_discount( $coupon_code ) ){
        WC()->cart->add_discount( $coupon_code ); // apply the coupon discount
        WC()->session->__unset('coupon_code'); // remove coupon code from session
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).* Tested and works

> Inspired from this answer code, [Lukasz Wiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/853558/lukasz-wiktor) has published a plugin: [Woo Coupon URL](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-coupon-url/)

Comment: How to remove session value after the coupon applied successfully??

Comment: and also when trying this code i getting this error message "Sorry, this coupon is only valid for an initial payment and the cart does not require an initial payment."

Comment: @developerme Sorry you are right… **apologies…** I have updated my code try it again. Thanks

Comment: Yes its working for me Thank You But when i removing coupon apply filed on the checkout page its not working...form could you please help me for that??

Comment: Inspired by your answer I created a WooCommerce plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-coupon-url/

Comment: @LoicTheAztec in the source code https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/woo-coupon-url/trunk/public/class-woo-coupon-url-public.php#L106

Comment: @LukaszWiktor Nice thanks… I have mention your plugin at the end of this thread.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a million!!!

Comment: @LoicTheAztec - Thanks for this. Should it still work on latest version of WooCommerce? I've tried it out, and had no effect. Any thoughts?