# How to add to cart with coupon from the URL Link

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, coupon

In WooCommerce, I would like to add to cart with a coupon from a URL Link.

How this can be done? Is it possible?

Comment: You can use the code [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48225502/3730754) Then your Add to cart URL will be something like: `http://www.example.com/?add-to-cart=37&coupon_code=mycouponcode` *(where `mycouponcode` is your coupon code name)*

Comment: Thanks Loic, I`m trying to add 2 products to the cart and add the coupon, but using your URL is not working, it only adds the products without the coupon

Comment: Please explain how do you add 2 products in cart from an url in your question editing it… Without that clear information and related details, is not possible to test anything.